# C# VSCode запуск

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, запуск

Я работаю в `Visual Studio Code` и для запуска использую плагин `Code runner`.

У меня отлично запускаются `C++`, `Python` файлы. А `C#` - не работает. Так как запускает через `scripts`, а не через `.net`. Можно ли добавить `dotnet run` для запуска файлов `.cs`? Будь то в расширение `Code runner` или `C#`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В `settings.json` добавьте следущее

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
     ......   
    "csharp": "cd $dir && dotnet run",
   
},
```

Чтобы открыть `settings.json`:

1. Нажмите <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. В строке введите `Preferences: settings Open (JSON)`
3. Внесите вышеуказанное изменение
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: А что делать если "code-runner.executorMap" помечает как ошибку?

Comment: @HardRoma `code runner` расширение установлено? Вот это https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner

Comment: да установлено. И прекрасно работает на питоне и C++.

Comment: Если даже с ошибкой сохраните, работает? я надеюсь вы удалили мои многоточия

Comment: проверил, работает, большое спасибо)))!!! А есть какая-то формула для добавления других языков? Типа ("code-runner.executorMap": {
  "язык": "cd $dir && команда запуска",).

Comment: @HardRoma есть, посмотрите в документации к расширению, там есть перечень. Можете отметить данный ответ как принятый)